# Requesting additional Facebook Login permissions with AWS Mobile iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, amazon-web-services, authentication, permissions

I am using AWS Mobile for iOS and I would like to request additional permissions from the Facebook Login (such as user_birthday and other Facebook permissions).

On the Android package you can download from the AWS Mobile HUB it's as simple as modifying the FacebookSignInProvider.java class that is included with the Android package and modify the Facebook loginWithReadPermissions function as such:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(signInActivity,
Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday"));
```

But I am also using the iOS Obj-C source package you obtain by building with the AWS Mobile HUB, and only the header files are provided, so it is not possible to modify such implementation.

Any tips?

Regards.

Comment: Hey there friend! Did you find a solution to this question? I am struggling with the same problem :(

Comment: @LucasSenechal I tried the solution posted below and it worked for me. Hopefully it will work for you too!

Comment: Genius man! ill check it out and see if this works! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue by overwriting the AWSFacebookSignInProvider class, so I ended up with a header and implementation files as such:

AWSFacebookSignInProviderCustom.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AWSMobileHubHelper/AWSSignInProvider.h>
#import <AWSMobileHubHelper/AWSFacebookSignInProvider.h>

@interface AWSFacebookSignInProviderCustom : AWSFacebookSignInProvider <AWSSignInProvider>

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;

@end
```

And then AWSFacebookSignInProviderCustom.m

```
#import "AWSFacebookSignInProviderCustom.h"
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>


@interface AWSFacebookSignInProviderCustom()

@property (strong, nonatomic) FBSDKLoginManager *facebookLogin;

@end

@implementation AWSFacebookSignInProviderCustom

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static AWSFacebookSignInProviderCustom *_sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [AWSFacebookSignInProviderCustom new];
    });

    return _sharedInstance;
}

- (void)login
{

    if (!self.facebookLogin)
        self.facebookLogin = [FBSDKLoginManager new];

    [self.facebookLogin logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_birthday"]
                                         handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
                                             if (error) {
                                                 NSLog(@"Error!");
                                             } else if (result.isCancelled)
                                             {
                                                 // Login canceled, do nothing
                                                 NSLog(@"Cancelled!");
                                             } else {
                                                 NSLog(@"FSBKDAccess Token: %@", [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]);
                                                 [[AWSFacebookSignInProvider sharedInstance] login];

                                             }
                                         }];
}

@end
```

So basically that overrides the login button permissions adding any custom permissions you might want. Afterwards, it just calls the standard AWSFacebookSignInProvider login method to complete things as usual.

On your Login Controller, for the handleFacebookLogin method, just use this AWSFacebookSignInProviderCustom class.

That did the trick for me. I hope it can help other people out. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you downloaded the project from AWS MobileHub, include the AWSMobileHubHelper Framework and AWSMobileClient.swift

```
AWSFacebookSignInProvider.sharedInstance().setPermissions(["public_profile"]);
```